# iOS - Get Twitter display name and time

Tags: ios, twitter

I have successfully been able to output a users timeline using:

```
ACAccount *account = _currentUserAccount;

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//parameters
[parameters setObject:@"800" forKey:@"count"];
[parameters setObject:@"false" forKey:@"include_rts"];
[parameters setObject:@"true" forKey:@"contributor_details"];

SLRequest *timelinePosts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:parameters];

timelinePosts.account = account;

[timelinePosts performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

    self.userPosts = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

    if ([self.userPosts count] != 0) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.tableView reloadData];

        });

    }

}];
```

but what i don't know and understand how to do is get the users display name with this code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Twitter's [api docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline), it's under a tweet's `user['name']` field. So in your table view row where you are displaying this, you can access the `user` dictionary, then the `name` field to get it.